# Windows Mobile 5 erro ler XML

Tags: xml, linq, windows-mobile-5

Estou com diviculdades em obter os valores do seguinte XML

```
    <ArrayOf    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServicePedido_v7"    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<V>    
<D>S</D> 
<I>Z</I> 
<V>1</V> </V> <V>    
<D>S</D>    
<I>Z</I> 
<V>2</V> </V>    
</ArrayOf>
```

Para ler utilizei o seguinte código:

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(url);

            XDocument x = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);




            var EmpData = from emp in x.Descendants("V")
                          select new M
                          {
                              V = Convert.ToInt32(emp.Descendants("V").First().Value),
                              I = emp.Descendants("I").First().Value,
                              D = emp.Descendants("D").First().Value
                          };

            List<M> aux = EmpData.ToList();
```

Nao consigo obter os valores.

Comment: `EmpData` vem vazio?

Comment: Windows Mobile :P.... te recomendo a estudar windows phone 8

Comment: sim vem vazio a lista

Comment: Já uso, mas para PDA tem que ser esta versão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás a ter dois problemas:

1. Não estás a especificar o *namespace*
2. `Descendents` vai encontrar todos os descendentes. Inclusive os `V`s dentro dos `V`s.

Experimenta assim:

```
var EmpData = from emp in x.Root.Elements("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServicePedido_v7}V")
    select new 
    {
        V = XmlConvert.ToInt32(emp.Element("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServicePedido_v7}V").Value),
        I = emp.Element("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServicePedido_v7}I").Value,
        D = emp.Element("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServicePedido_v7}D").Value
    };
```

Ou:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServicePedido_v7");

var EmpData = from emp in x.Root.Elements(ns+"V")
    select new 
    {
        V = XmlConvert.ToInt32(emp.Element(ns+"V").Value),
        I = emp.Element(ns+"I").Value,
        D = emp.Element(ns+"D").Value
    };
```

Ou ainda:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServicePedido_v7");
var vName = ns + "V";
var iName = ns + "I";
var dName = ns + "D";

var EmpData = from emp in x.Root.Elements(vName)
    select new 
    {
        V = XmlConvert.ToInt32(emp.Element(vName).Value),
        I = emp.Element(iName).Value,
        D = emp.Element(dName).Value
    };
```